# Como mostrar una consulta en un dataGridView?

Tags: c#

Tengo 2 textBox (textBox1 y textBox2), la consulta que quiero es esta:

El `production_line` seria el `textBox2` y el `item_number` es el `textBox1`

```
 select * from tbl_volumen2 where production_line ='L1B4' AND item_number ='VPJG7F-10849-BD'
```

Al hacer esta consulta quisiera que me mostrara todos los datos que existen en mi tabla **`tbl_volumen2`** en un `dataGridView` que tengo en un Windows Form en C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un código bastante sencillo para colocar los datos de una consulta en tu `dataGridView`:

```
var consulta= "select * from tbl_volumen2 where production_line ='L1B4' AND item_number ='VPJG7F-10849-BD'";
 var c = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString); // Tu String de conexión
 var adaptador= new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, c); 

 var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptador);
 var ds = new DataSet();
 adaptador.Fill(ds);
 dataGridView.ReadOnly = true; 
 dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
            DataTable tabla = new Datatable();
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(datosConexion)) {
                conexion.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conexion);
                adaptador.Fill(tabla);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tabla;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias n.n