# Mostrar registros de MySQL en un DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, sql, datagrid

Tengo una base de datos que almacena registros desde un Form MDI padre, hasta allí todo bien.

El problema surge cuando requiero que los registros de la BD, se muestren en un DataGridView que tengo dentro de un MDI hijo. He corroborado distintas fuentes:

[Como mostrar una consulta en un dataGridView?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64209/como-mostrar-una-consulta-en-un-datagridview)

[Tutorial Como Mostrar datos MySql en un DataGridview C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=injytdtlY74&t=85s)

**Más no han sido exitosas mis consultas, ya que el DataGridView no muestra los datos.** Enseguida mi código del DatGridView y el respectivo Query:

```
var consulta = "select * from (select ID, Nombre, ApPaterno, ApMaterno, Carrera from alumno) alumno,(select ID, Nombre, ApPaterno, ApMaterno, Profesion from profesor) profesor;";
            var c = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=escuela; Uid=miusuario; pwd=micontrasenia");
            var adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, c);

            var commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adaptador);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adaptador.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

**He aquí mi interfaz incluyendo el MDI hijo en el que deseo que se muestre el registro: Form3 es el MDI hijo en el que se mostrará los registros, Form1 es el MDI padre.**

[image: Form3 es el MDI hijo en el que se mostrarán los campos, Form1 es el MDI padre]

Desconozco sí tenga algo que ver con que esté realizando el Query dentro de un MDI. Gracias.

**Edición:**
*Cercioro el Query que ejecuto en la base de datos en WorkBench para corroborar su respuesta:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si hace falta el resumen de la base datos:
Tengo una BD **escuela** dentro de escuela genero dos tablas: **alumno** y **profesor**, y deseo incluir en un a consulta la impresión de ambas tablas.

Comment: Tu consulta me parece rara. ¿Si la ejecutas directamente en el DBMS sí arroja datos?

Comment: @A.Cedano si, de hecho la consulta la saqué directamente del WorkBench. Lo que hace el query es mostrar todos los registros de tablas independientes.

Comment: Entendido. ¿Puedes probar que el objeto conexión se está creando correctamente?

Comment: Sí, reutilicé el mismo comando de conexión a la hora de almacenar registros nuevos.

Comment: Dado que se producen columnas con el mismo nombre, quizá convenga otorgarles un alias. No estoy seguro que sea eso, pero podría darte problemas. Prueba la consulta así: `var consulta = "select * from (select ID, Nombre, ApPaterno, ApMaterno, Carrera from alumno) alumno,(select ID p_ID, Nombre p_Nombre, ApPaterno p_ApPaterno, ApMaterno p_ApMaterno, Profesion from profesor) profesor;";`

Comment: Sin éxito. Estoy creyendo que puede ser la conexión que estoy reutilizando, ¿Pero tendría que ver alguna diferencia entre insertar y consultar? Yo no lo creo, igual seguiré Googleando por si encuentro algo.

Comment: prueba agregar gridview1.databind(); despues de definir el datasource y antes de cerrar la conexion

Comment: Terminé realizandolo de otra manera. Generé otro Form fuera del MDI padre, de esa manera se implementa sin problema la lista de los registros. No sé que tenga que ver el MDI con el DataGridView a la hora de mostrar el registro. Gracias.